# rails jquery hello world not working with elastic bean stalk install

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a basic rails jquery hello world that works on my localhost:3000/service/jqtest that displays the output on a browser as shown below

[image]

But when the same code is pushed to AWS using the EB cli commands. Only the "html" line is displayed on the browser after the ebs install and is puzzling since jquery comes bundled with "Rails 4.2.4". I added the "puma gem" to the Gemfile.  It most likely has to do with incorrect path to assets etc. Would help if anyone has pointers on overcoming this issue... Here are the contents of the ERB file -

```
    This line is using pure a HTML element. Do you see the blue line of text generated by JQuery below?<br>
<font color="#0000FF">
<div id="msgid"></div>
</font>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#msgid").html("This blue line is generated using JQuery. If you do not have jQuery intsalled correctly, you will not see this line!");
});
```

Here are the errors that I see on the chrome js console -

```
<script src="/assets/jquery.self-a714331225dda820228db323939889f149aec0127aeb06255646b616ba1ca419.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script> Failed To load resource. The server responded with a status of 404 (Not found) 
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.self-d456baa54c1fa6be2ec3711f0a72ddf7a5b2f34a6b4f515f33767d6207b7d4b3.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script> Failed To load resource. The server responded with a status of 404 (Not found) 
<script src="/assets/turbolinks.self-c37727e9bd6b2735da5c311aa83fead54ed0be6cc8bd9a65309e9c5abe2cbfff.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>Failed To load resource. The server responded with a status of 404 (Not found)
```

Any pointers would help!

Comment: try to add the jquery-rails gem

Answer (score 0):

The key issue was that stuff on my local had files that were not committed into git. If it is not committed locally "eb deploy" does not seem to pickup the appropriate files. Moving files to staging did not help...

I verified it today - made local changes to a file, ran the app locally - it carries the change that was made. If you "eb deploy" it, then ssh into your ec2 instance and check the file's contents you may not see the change in the deployed source code. This behavior may be ephemeral but I can categorically  vouch for the fact that I did not see the change deployed unless the code was committed!